# Outlook automatically save every sent email as a text file

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I want Outlook to automatically save every sent email as a text file in a specified directory.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Why, whats the end goal ?  Have you tried other email clients ?

Comment: Please have a read of https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask, then come back and edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Wayne Walton,

Method 1: Using Outlook Rules and VBA Script

```
Enable Developer Tab:
    In Outlook, go to File > Options.
    Click on Customize Ribbon.
    Check the box for Developer in the right column.
    Click OK.

Open Visual Basic for Applications (VBA):
    Click on the Developer tab.
    Click Visual Basic.

Create a New Module:
    Right-click on any item in the project explorer on the left.
    Choose Insert > Module.

Paste the VBA Script:
    Copy and paste the following VBA script into the module:
```

vba

Sub SaveSentEmail(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objFileSystem As Object
Dim objTextFile As Object
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strFolderPath As String

```
' Set the folder path where you want to save the text files
strFolderPath = "C:\Path\To\Your\Folder\"

' Create the file name using the email subject
strFileName = strFolderPath & Item.Subject & ".txt"

' Create a FileSystemObject
Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Create or open the text file
Set objTextFile = objFileSystem.CreateTextFile(strFileName, True)

' Write the email body to the text file
objTextFile.Write Item.Body

' Close the text file
objTextFile.Close
```

End Sub

```
Create a Rule to Run the Script:
    Go back to Outlook.
    Go to File > Manage Rules & Alerts.
    Click New Rule.
    Select Apply rule on messages I send.
    Click Next until you reach the Finish Rule Setup window.
    Check Run a script and click on a script in the bottom box.
    Select the SaveSentEmail script and click Add, then OK.
    Complete the rule setup and click Finish.
```

Method 2: Using Third-Party Tools

There are also third-party tools available that can automatically save sent emails to a specified folder or in various formats. Some popular ones include:

```
CodeTwo Outlook Export: A paid tool that allows you to save Outlook emails to different formats automatically.

MessageExport by Encryptomatic: Another paid tool that provides advanced options for saving Outlook emails.
```

Comment: Hi Nelson, I get to Click Next until you reach the Finish Rule Setup window. But I don't have the "Run a script" in the bottom box.